# How to nurse a plant damaged from shipping back to health?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care, leaves

I ordered a Peperomia Argyreia (Watermelon) and it arrived today. 5 out of 7 of the leaves have some or a lot of browning/blackening on the underside of them, with the 3 biggest ones all having some bad damage. the stems are drooping a bit as well, and I'm not quite sure if it is due to shipping stress, water (the soil is a little but not very moist), or just not having enough light. Shipping took about 4 days. I want to nurse this plant back to its former health but I'm not quite sure what the best way is to go about doing that? Should I cut the leaves, should I repot it, etc? Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nursing a plant back to health takes time, so don't expect an over night change. It is very common for plants to experience stress from shipping, being in a container for 4 days means that your plant hasn't had a chance to photosynthesize and make food in 4 days so slowly get it closer to light. I wouldn't cut the damaged leaves, the plant can still photosynthesize through those and make use of them. In the future they might fall off on their own or you can clip them as the plant starts growing new leaves to support itself. I'd say stick to the usual care for a peperomia and wait for new leaves